# Android XML-RPC Serialization Issue

Tags: android, ioexception

I am attempting to use Android XML-RPC and for some calls I get the following exception:

```
W/System.err( 837): java.io.IOException: Cannot serialize java.lang.Object@43759748
```

It looks like it is having troubles serializing the returned data, but I cannot find much documentation on how to actually use Android XML-RPC.

The way I am using Android XML-RPC is as follows:

```
Object response = (Object)client.call("sales_order.list", new Object());
```

This one is pretty odd. I have tried setting this call up in a few different ways (using HashMaps, not passing second variable, etc) and the response I get is that sales_order.list is not a valid Method.

I have been able to login to the service using the following code:

```
this.sessionId = (String)client.call("login", this.apiUserName, this.apiPassword);
```

Does anyone have any ideas or a good resource on how to use Android XML-RPC?

Igor

http://mobilerockets.com/

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same problem. I think it's because xml-rpc doesn't know how to serialize objects (or custom classes/structs).